# Symfony 2.1 handle and store one-to-abstract-one relationship

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.1, abstract, one-to-one

I have a situation like this:

I have an entity **human** and a form to type in the data for humans.
The human can have a pet that can be a **cat** or a **dog**.

So i generalized cat and dog to a **petAbstract** class.
Which is stored as single_table inheritance type.

So the entity human stores one petAbstract object.

The steps i go:

I have a Form to type in the data for human.

Then i have a form for each pet. So they can have their own properties.
Then i have a third form to group all the pet-forms together.
This third form has a drop down to switch the pet-forms.

But now the mapped request contains an array with all the pet-forms.

My Problem is now:
Is there a place outside of the controller where i can read the chosen option and decide what object is associated with the human?

Comment: I know the documentation link: [How to Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)

But it handels only the implementation of an interface with one configurable object-implementation

Comment: I'v done it by simplifying the complexity.